# Making a post call from within sinatra

Tags: sinatra

Basically, I want to accept a request at certain URLs, and essentially redirect to another but include some data with the redirect - funneling several URLs into a single one with data based on the originally requested URL.

There are other ways of doing this, I realize, but to keep the URL clean I prefer to do it this way and pass info by POST, like doing a curl -F.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

There are a whole mess of http clients out there for Ruby. To name a few, there are httpclient, ruby-httpclient and patron. A quick glance through them leaves me feeling like I like [Patron](https://github.com/toland/patron) best, due to the fact that it relies on libcurl:

```
hc = Patron::Session.new
hc.base_url = "http://search.twitter.com/"
hc.post("/foo/stuff", "Some data I want to post", {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"})
```

ruby-httpclient looks somewhat similar, but there are less examples on their [page](http://code.google.com/p/ruby-httpclient/wiki/Home), so harder to immediately grok:

```
client = Net::HTTPClient.new
html = client.get 'http://www.google.com.au'
```

I haven't hacked around with any of them, so YMMV but those are good places to start!

UPDATE:

After looking in my [Service-Oriented Design with Ruby and Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321659368) (link to Amazon) book, they highly recommended [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) for doing http requests. After glancing at it, I have to agree. Looks very solid and easy to use. Hope this helps!